# publicar archivos en IIS 7 de manera local conc#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

amigos buen día podrian ayudarme para ver porque no puedo subir archivos a mi servidor local IIS7, el código del controlador es el siguiente.

```
[ActionName("Importar_excel")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Importar_excell(int MtoProcedimientoId)
    {
        var isValid = true;

        var user = db.MtoUsuarios.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user == null)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }


        if ((Request.Files["FileUpload1"].ContentLength != 0) && (MtoProcedimientoId != 0))
        {

            var procedimiento = db.MtoProcedimientos.Find(MtoProcedimientoId);

            string extension = Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName).ToLower();
            string connString = "";

            string[] validFileTypes = { ".xls", ".xlsx", ".csv" };

            var Folder = "~/Content/Uploads/Procedimiento/Requerimiento";
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["FileUpload1"];

            string path1 = $"{Server.MapPath(Folder)}";
            string path2 = $"{path1}/{Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName}";

            if (!Directory.Exists(path1))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(path1));
            }
            if (validFileTypes.Contains(extension))
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path2))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path2);
                }

                var UploadFile = FilesHelper.UploadPhoto(file, Folder, Request.Files["FileUpload1"].FileName);
                if (UploadFile)
                {
                    if (extension == ".csv")
                    {
                        dt = Utilities.ConvertCSVtoDataTable(path2);
                        ViewBag.Data = dt;
                    }
                    //Connection String to Excel Workbook  
                    else if (extension.Trim() == ".xls")
                    {
                        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path2 + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        dt = Utilities.ConvertXSLXtoDataTable(path1, connString);
                        ViewBag.Data = dt;
                    }
                    else if (extension.Trim() == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path2 + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        dt = Utilities.ConvertXSLXtoDataTable(path1, connString);
                        ViewBag.Data = dt;
                    }

                    /*============================================================
                     codigo para almacenar la informacion en la base de datos
                    ============================================================*/
                    DataColumn MtoUsuarioId = new DataColumn("MtoUsuarioId", typeof(int));
                    DataColumn MMtoProcedimientoId = new DataColumn("MtoProcedimientoId", typeof(int));
                    MtoUsuarioId.AllowDBNull = true;
                    MMtoProcedimientoId.AllowDBNull = true;

                    dt.Columns.Add(MtoUsuarioId);
                    dt.Columns.Add(MMtoProcedimientoId);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        row["MtoUsuarioId"] = user.MtoUsuarioId;
                        row["MtoProcedimientoId"] = MtoProcedimientoId;
                    }


                    var totregistro = db.MtoRequerimientos.Where(m => m.MtoProcedimientoId == MtoProcedimientoId);

                    if (totregistro.Count() == 0)
                    {

                        var response = DBRequerimiento.SaveReq(dt);
                        if (response.succeeded)
                        {
                            Success(string.Format("Éxito:<b>{0}</b>", "Migracion Realizada con Exito"), true);
                            return Json(new { success = response.succeeded });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Danger(string.Format("ERROR:<b>{0}</b>", response.Message), true);
                            isValid = response.succeeded;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isValid = false;
                        ViewBag.Error = "Ya existe requerimiento para este procedimiento";
                    }
                }                    
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Por favor suba archivos en .xls, .xlsx or .csv format";
                isValid = false;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "No se proporciono ningun archivo en formato .xls, .xlsx or .csv ";
        }


        ViewBag.MtoProcedimientoId = new SelectList(ComboHelper.GetProcedimientos(user.MtoCompaniaId, 1), "MtoProcedimientoId", "NoLicitacion");
        ViewBag.Data = dt;
        // return View();

        //return Json(new { data = obj, row = noOfRow, col = noOfCol }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return Json(new { success = isValid }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);





    }
```

ahora en el controller de utilidad tengo el siguiente código.

```
public static bool UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase File, string Folder, string Name)
    {
        if ((File == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Folder) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            string path = string.Empty;
            string pic = string.Empty;

            if (File != null)
            {

                path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Folder), Name);
                File.SaveAs(path);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    File.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

ahora en las pruebas cuando esta en desarrollo se publican los archivos muy bien, pero cuando lo subo al IIS 7, me dice que la carpeta no existe cuando ya revise y la carpeta si esta ya revise permiso y tengo permisos de lectura y escritura.

el error que me muestra e:

404: archivo o directorio no encontrado.
 Puede que se haya quitado el recurso que est� buscando, que se le haya
cambiado el nombre o que no est� disponible temporalmente.

podrías echarme una mano para saber en que estoy mal.

gracias

Comment: ¿Todos tus Action muestran el error 404, Get, Post, etc?, ¿o solo el Action Post **Importar_excel**?

Comment: solo el POST de Importar_Excel, en los demas casos no tengo problemas.

Comment: Debugea e indica en que línea te marca la excepcion por favor

Comment: cuando debugueo no marca ningun error, el error esta cuando publico la aplicacion en el IIS7 que esta en otra maquina, ahi es cuando no sube los permisos y me dice que la carpeta no existe

Comment: Ya le diste permisos a tu folder en el host, con el explorador de carpetas ve al forlder donde guardas los documentos click derecho --> Seguridad  agrega el usuario IUSR a la carpeta y le das permisos  de lectura y escritura.

Comment: ya tiene todos los permiso necesarios, sin embargo me dice que la carpeta no existe

Comment: Hola, en donde te lanza el error? por lo que veo en ese controller estas creando los directorios y el archivo. Podes localizar exactamente en que linea te da error?